# MySQL Track DDL changes history

Tags: mysql, ddl

I need to somehow store the changes made to database structure (on CREATE, DELETE, ALTER, RENAME). The goal is to create an api that will return to a client a list of changes made to the specified database structure since some date (user_who_made_changes, changes_date, DDL_query).

Is it possible with MySQL?

Unfortunately DDL triggers are not supported in MySQL.

I also looked at logging at MySQL (general or binary logging), but it seems there's no possibility to sort logged statements by specified schema.

Any ideas? Will be thankful for any advice.